# MGTwitterEngine and IOS 5.0.1 Not Working, works on IOS 4.x

Tags: ios, twitter, ios5, mgtwitterengine

I have been using the MGTwitterEngine and it is working fine on IOS 4.x, but does not work on IOS 5.x  I have downloaded the latest version, mattgemmell-MGTwitterEngine-e40658f, and integrated it with the same issue.  I am getting the following that I have only started to research, but this code does work fine on IOS 4.x

Here is the line, but works fine on IOS 4.x, assumine some sort of depreciation

```
[delegate parsedObject:(NSDictionary *)dictionary forRequest:identifier ofResponseType:responseType];

Instance method '-parsedObject:forRequest:ofResponseType:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')
```

delegate is type of

```
__weak NSObject <MGTwitterParserDelegate> *delegate; // weak ref
```

and is in the routine

```
- (void)_parsedObject:(NSDictionary *)dictionary
{
[parsedObjects addObject:dictionary];
if (deliveryOptions & MGTwitterEngineDeliveryIndividualResultsOption)
    if ([self _isValidDelegateForSelector:@selector(parsedObject:forRequest:ofResponseType:)])
        [delegate parsedObject:(NSDictionary *)dictionary forRequest:identifier ofResponseType:responseType];
}
```

And after setting a break on the routine, it looks like it is not getting called.....

So, we are back to the first question, anyone fix the issue where this twitter engine is not working on IOS 5.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS5 already has own Twitter Framework. You need to use it - [Twitter Framework Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Twitter/Reference/TwitterFrameworkReference/_index.html)

Comment: Well, I just did this and was hoping not to have to do this, two different user interfaces for the user.  But I guess we have to do what we have to do.